# Xamarin.Android RunOnUIThread and onTimedEvent delay/lags (I am trying to display a CountDown Timer)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, timer, xamarin.android

So I am creating an application that display the countdown from 3 to 0 and user can click retry which will start from 3 to 0 again. I have tvTimer(TextView) that display the countdown timer.

The codes work fine but sometimes it lag/delay, for example

When onCreate, the tvTimer.Text will display 3, 2, 1, 0 but when I click Retry button, SOMETIMES it display 3, 2, 2, 0.

Do you think its because of RunOnUIThread?

Heres my code

```
    int CountSeconds;
    Button retry;
    TextView tvTimer;
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Pagee);
        tvTimer = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvTimer);
        retry = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.retry);
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        play_timer();
        retry.Click += Retry_Click;
    }

    public void play_timer()
    {
         CountSeconds = 3; 
         aTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() => { tvTimer.Text = Convert.ToString(CountSeconds );});

        CountSeconds  = CountSeconds  - 1;

        if (CountSeconds  == 0)
        {
            CountSeconds  = 3;
            aTimer.Stop();
        }

    private void Retry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             play_timer();
    }
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: You run code on UI thread and change the value in another thread. This will be a race condition and either may happen before the other. Would be better to subtract first, then set the value, or do the whole subtraction in the same UI thread.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hi, thanks for the reply! So sorry but I am totally newbie and dont understand the subtract first then set the value, where should I subtract first ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you write code that runs on separate threads, like here

```
RunOnUiThread(() => { tvTimer.Text = Convert.ToString(CountSeconds );});

CountSeconds  = CountSeconds  - 1;
```

This means that either of these pieces may be run first, or they may even run simultaenously on a multi-core/CPU system. If `CountSeconds` is 3, for example, you may get 3 or 2 on the textbox.

To make sure things happen in more reproducible order you can reorder these things and move the `RunOnUiThread` to the end of the method. Then you can be sure the subtraction and check for zero happens first and only after that the textbox is set.

You can also move the whole logic inside the call to the UI thread so it happens at once in the same thread, for example:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => {
  CountSeconds  = CountSeconds  - 1;

  tvTimer.Text = Convert.ToString(CountSeconds );

  if (CountSeconds  == 0)
  {
    CountSeconds  = 3;
    aTimer.Stop();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. I had one last problem tho. What if I click the 'Retry' button when the onTimedEvent is running? It runs on different thread as well right? So let's say it runs from 3, 2, then I click Retry, which will set value of CountSeconds to 3 again. What would happen? I tried it and it seems to be a mess (number update delays)

Comment: @CarmenC The event runs for a very short time so that shouldn't matter. But you should stop the timer, reset the value and then start the timer again if you want it to stay on sync. There is a theoretical possibility that this happens exactly when the timer event is running, so if it matters you can always add locking to the system to make sure you don't do anything while the UI is being updated.